# How to convert the CDS Upfront Fee into the Traded Spread?

Tags: spread, cds

If I know all the economics of a CDS trade included the Upfront Settlement Fee from the ISDA CDS Model, how can I convert that amount back to Traded Spead? Can some help explain the process?

Comment: This is all explained on the official website: http://www.cdsmodel.com/cdsmodel/documentation.html?# under "Standard CDS contract converter specification"

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is the Traded Spread? Do you want to convert the upfront fee into a par spread that leads to a zero CDS value, or a spread so that the CDS value is equal to the upfront fee?

Comment: Here is real example of what I am looking to achieve. Lets say I only know the following information: Trade Date: 2/9/17  Maturity Date: 12/20/21 Notional: 10mm Fixed Coupon:500bps Upfront Fee: $270,324 and assuming 40% recovery, how could I determine the Traded Spread from this information? I believe we are saying Traded Spread and Par Spread are the same.

Comment: Are you trying to find out the traded (par) spread on 2/9/17 or today? If the answer is today, you need to access CDS market data to construct a spread curve. Markit is the standard here.

Answer (score 3):

You should check this answer: [How to interpret the 'price' of a CDS?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/30258/how-to-interpret-the-price-of-a-cds/30263#30263)

It explains the relation between spread and upfront.
In your particular case you might consider using a simple model mentioned at the end of that answer:

> A simple model for the value of a short protection CDS can be found if you write
>
> V = (C-S) x RPV01
>
> where
>
> RPV01 = (1−exp(−gT))/g
>
> and C is the coupon, S is the par CDS spread, T is the remaining life in years and
>
> g=r+S/(1−R)g=r+S/(1−R)
>
> where r is the risk-free (Libor) rate and R is the expected recovery rate, usually set to 40%.

Comment: Thank you this information.  The issue that I am finding with this equation is that I am trying to solve for S (CDS Spread) and when finding the value for RPV01 the CDS Spread is embedded in the calculation ( by solving for "g").  What is the Libor value here or how would I solve for Libor?

Comment: @ChrisN In your example maturity is in 5 years, so as a risk free rate you might use US treasury bond with 5y maturity. That's right, the equation i ls not directly solvable for S, so you might consider using a numerical method to find a solution for that equation

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you need a quick estimate, you could use $T$ as a rough approximation for the RPV01.

$$
s \approx c - V/T
$$